# There is no column for User Name in the 'WMIC process' output

Tags: wmic

The Processes tab of the Windows Task Manager shows several columns with information, one of which being User Name of the user that owns the process.
Using the command WMIC process (from an administrator-started cmd.exe) gives me the same sort of information, but I can not find any column for the user name. How can I find out which user started the process with WMIC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Owner can be retrieved using GetOwner method on win32_process class instances.
I would suggest using PowerShell for that, where it's pretty simple:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process | 
    Select-Object Name, @{ 
        Name = 'Owner'
        Expression = { 
            $_.GetOwner().User 
        }
    }
```

If you have to use wmic, than you can hack your way through by mixing results of:

```
wmic process get Name
```

...with `call GetOwner` e.g:

```
@echo off
echo Domain\User,Machine,ProcessName,ProcessID,WorkingSetSize
(for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims=, eol= " %%P in ('wmic process get ProcessId /format:csv') do @call :AddOwner %%P) 2> nul
goto :EOF

:AddOwner
SET Process=%1
(for /f "skip=5 tokens=1,2 delims==; " %%O in ('wmic process WHERE ProcessID^=%Process% Call GetOwner') do @call :BuildOwner %%O %%P) > nul
for /f "skip=1 tokens=* eol= " %%L in ('wmic process WHERE ProcessID^=%Process% GET Name^, ProcessID^, WorkingSetSize /format:csv') do @SET INFO=%%L
echo %DOMAIN%\%USER%,%INFO%
goto :EOF

    :BuildOwner
    SET PARAM=%1
    SET VALUE=%~2
    IF [%PARAM%]==[Domain] SET DOMAIN=%VALUE%
    IF [%PARAM%]==[User] SET USER=%VALUE%
    goto :EOF
```

Comment: Thanks. Forgot to mention that I was actually looking for a .bat or .vbs solution. I suppose your solution works fine, but I've not verified it since I don't know the first thing about PowerShell. But a Google search for WMI GetOwner brought me to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and I found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

To get the owners of all of the *taskeng.exe* processes (Windows Task Scheduler processes for individual tasks), run this from an 'admin' *Command Prompt* window:

```
wmic process where "name='taskeng.exe'" call GetOwner
```

Comment: This gives following result and hence is useless: `Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 2;
};`

Comment: @Dominique What about just `wmic process`?

Comment: in that case you don't get the correct name, at least not for `WmiPrvSE.exe` process: in task manager there is `LOCAL SERVICE`, `NETWORK SERVICE` and `SYSTEM`, while `wmic process` yields only `DOMINIQUEDS`, which is my username at my PC.

Comment: @Dominique Are you running the command in an 'admin' Command Prompt window?

Comment: No, I was not aware this could make a difference.

Comment: @Dominique In a 'non-admin' Command Prompt window, you won't be able to access the full list of processes, even if the user for which you're logged-in is an admin.

Comment: How can this be used "call GetOwner" when using a get list.. like 
    wmic process where name="taskeng.exe" get caption,commandline,processid ?

Comment: @Vnge I'm not sure what you're asking exactly but you can almost certainly get a better answer by creating your own question and linking to this one.